# Trezor not showing correct balance

Tags: balance, trezor

Sent .10 from my Electrum to my trezor. Now more than 30 comfirmations, but not showing on my Trezor Balance. Put in a ticket with support have not heard back. Here is my trezor receiving address and the block explorer validates confirmations. 1PZz1GAhtVx4nWg4Me85jFe3Xg3anoGPLR
Sept-7/17
Any ideas. Would like to have the funds recorded so I can spend them.

Comment: So I see [you moved them](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/1133a9f13708649c0f7aa431013c75a87a0e87efc92ee0b293f10107f7d3c3b8), (or someone else did).

Answer (score 1):

> Sent .10 from my Electrum to my trezor

Yes you did:

[blockexplorer.com/tx/f5e5e6f4de4298a1d74ac3f3ba3116e0b80e97b2373da987766a2d5c27541da6](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/f5e5e6f4de4298a1d74ac3f3ba3116e0b80e97b2373da987766a2d5c27541da6)

But then you sent it somewhere else afterwards:

[blockexplorer.com/tx/2e4d4cf6f0a6bca1ec9489cc39bf6c6a6036a19ef10db66e42fd2052f37f466f](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/2e4d4cf6f0a6bca1ec9489cc39bf6c6a6036a19ef10db66e42fd2052f37f466f)

If you follow it forward, you'll see that the majority currently unspent (0.09373173 BTC) was last sent to address:
[1CMoma2Qq5SdaynYaU4yJrLdhQ7mFFsREN](https://blockexplorer.com/address/1CMoma2Qq5SdaynYaU4yJrLdhQ7mFFsREN)

**Edit:** It was later moved, so I suppose you have control of funds again: [blockexplorer.com/tx/1133a9f13708649c0f7aa431013c75a87a0e87efc92ee0b293f10107f7d3c3b8](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/1133a9f13708649c0f7aa431013c75a87a0e87efc92ee0b293f10107f7d3c3b8)